# ASP.NET MVC Session State

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to tell if a visitor to a site is new, or just the same one over and over again, for the purpose of a hit counter?

Sessions don't really seem to exist in MVC, so I know I can't really use them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell if a visitor to a site is new, or just the same one over and over again, for the purpose of a hit counter?

There's not a 100% reliable way due to the stateless nature of the web but for the purposes of a counter, setting a cookie and checking whether it's there or not is adequate for the most cases.

> Sessions don't really seem to exist in MVC, so I know I can't really use them...

This is not true. You can use `Session` in ASP.NET MVC too. Although, in general, you should avoid server-side state as much as possible when you don't need it to ease scalability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions in ASP.NET MVC, but as Mehrdad points out, storing this kind of information on the server is not the way to go about it--use JavaScript cookies instead. And let your clients do the "heavy lifting".

Quircksmode has a [**great article**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) on using JavaScript cookies.